How to create a custom view with a linear gradient border in Android?
I am trying to create a custom view in Android that has a linear gradient border with rounded corners, similar to the one shown in these image:
 
I've written the following custom view class in Kotlin, but I am having trouble getting the gradient border to appear correctly. Here is the code I am using:
class GradientBorderView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val borderPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 8f // Adjust the border thickness as needed
    }

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        color = Color.TRANSPARENT // Set background to transparent
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val rect = RectF(
            borderPaint.strokeWidth / 2,
            borderPaint.strokeWidth / 2,
            width - borderPaint.strokeWidth / 2,
            height - borderPaint.strokeWidth / 2,
        )

        // Draw the background with rounded corners
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 20f, 20f, backgroundPaint)

        // Create a path for the gradient border
        val path = Path().apply {
            addRoundRect(rect, 20f, 20f, Path.Direction.CW)
        }

        // Set the shader with the linear gradient for the border
        val gradient = LinearGradient(
            0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), 0f,
            intArrayOf(
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.parseColor("#56A1C8"),
                Color.parseColor("#3A4877"),
                Color.parseColor("#E49460"),
                Color.parseColor("#56A1C8"),
            ),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 0.9f, 1f),
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )

        borderPaint.shader = gradient

        // Draw the border with rounded corners
        canvas.drawPath(path, borderPaint)
    }
}

I am using this custom view in my XML layout:
<production.zofeur.customer.app.utils.GradientBorderView
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

This is the result:

What I have tried:

Adjusting the RectF dimensions.
Tweaking the LinearGradient colors and positions.
Ensuring the strokeWidth is set properly.

Despite my efforts the gradient border does not appear as expected. The gradient does not seem to blend smoothly, and the colors do not transition as they should. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve a smooth linear gradient border with rounded corners as shown in the image?

gradient border does not appear as expected can you post image of expected image ?

Seems it would be easier to build this as an XML drawable and make it the background drawable for whatever pre-existing view class you like.

@BobSmith i already posted above and below image is that what i made already

XML Drawable how? @Tenfour04

There are tons of articles about creating drawables in xml for Android. Way too much to explain here in a comment.

I looked at this.  You could create a Drawable in code, but not XML.  Gradient only applies to the fill of a shape, not the stroke.

What you mean? @krislarson can you give any example? or code? like you saying i shoudl take SVG of this then use it in drawable then to XML right?

Drawable is just an abstract class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable There are XML resources for common drawables, but what you want to do can't be composed with XML drawable resources.

@krislarson yes this cant be acheieved using drawable Vector or Drawable Resource

The result I see makes sense for the code, except it looks like the fourth parameter was originally height.toFloat() instead of 0.  With two TRANSPARENT colors out to 50%, about half the border is undrawn, as I would suspect.
Based on the expected image, maybe you want the gradient line to be 45 degrees as though the view were square. In that case, use width.toFloat() for both x1 and y1.  This creates a 45 degree gradient line.  (Note: this only works if the width is greater than the height, otherwise use height.toFloat() for both x1 and y1)
Also stick another color in there so it's not half transparent.
So I think this might be closer to what you want:
        val gradient = LinearGradient(
            0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), width.toFloat(),
            intArrayOf(
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.parseColor("#56A1C8"),
                Color.parseColor("#3A4877"),
                Color.parseColor("#56A1C8"),
                Color.parseColor("#E49460"),
                Color.parseColor("#56A1C8"),
            ),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 0.9f, 1f),
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )

In sum, remember your geometry lessons and think about the angle of the gradient line that will be created by x0, y0 to x1, y1 and think about how the colors are distributing (ex. at the halfway point on your line from x0, y0 to x1, y1 the color will be #3A4877.  These correspond to the third entries in the colors and position arrays.)
For me, it's easier to visualize the gradient as the full rectangle and the border as a clipping mask on top for the colors.

You mean i should make it as rectangle? basically i want it rectangle thou

i use it but still i am not able to have the expected result

Help me to understand the difference between what you are seeing and what you want to see.
